# Converting Suprema Biostar C++ code to C#

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, biometrics

I got the Biostation T2 from Suprema, they provided a wrapped Dll made with C#, they also provide example using: VB6, VB.net, C++ and C#.Most of the documentation is in C++ and am having a hard time trying to convert that logic to C#.I am unable to enroll a user using the below functions in the pastie.Mainly cause am not sure if the logic in C# and C++ matches up.

See the [C++ code for enrolling user and my C# attempt](http://pastie.org/9883044) pastie

I get error attempted to read or write protected memory as captured here[image]

Here ia a link of the sdk samples they provide [sdk samples in vc,c#,C++](http://webhard.suprema.co.kr//ExFd/8730/9186.zip)

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your p/invoke problem.  There's no way for us to reproduce this with what you have posted.

Comment: @dbc my question Is does the C++ code interpretation to C# code match up correctly?Let me try edit it down a notch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have no way of compiling and testing your code with what you have shown us.  That being said, comparing the c++ and c# side by side, I see the following inconsistencies:

1. The c++ has the following code:

   ```
   unsigned char* templateBuf = (unsigned char*)malloc( userHeader.numOfFinger * 2 * BS_TEMPLATE_SIZE );
   int bufPos = 0;
   for( int i = 0; i < userHeader.numOfFinger * 2; i++ )
   {
       result = BS_ScanTemplate( handle, templateBuf + bufPos );
       bufPos += BS_TEMPLATE_SIZE;
   }
   ```

   This code calls `BS_ScanTemplate` multiple times and stores the results sequentially in a byte array.  Your code does the following:

   ```
       byte[] templateBuf = new byte[userHdr.numOfFinger * 2 * BS_TEMPLATE_SIZE];
       int bufPos = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < userHdr.numOfFinger * 2; i++)
       {
           templateBuf = new byte[userHdr.numOfFinger * 2 * BS_TEMPLATE_SIZE * bufPos];
           result = BSSDK.BS_ScanTemplate(m_Handle, templateBuf);
           bufPos += BS_TEMPLATE_SIZE;
       }
   ```

   Rather than storing the results of `BS_ScanTemplate` sequentially, this code throws away the results from each preceding call by reallocating the array.  Perhaps you want something like:

   ```
       byte[] templateBuf = new byte[userHdr.numOfFinger * 2 * BS_TEMPLATE_SIZE];
       for (int i = 0, bufPos = 0; i < userHdr.numOfFinger * 2; i++)
       {
           byte[] singleBuf = new byte[BS_TEMPLATE_SIZE];
           result = BSSDK.BS_ScanTemplate(m_Handle, singleBuf);
           Array.Copy(singleBuf, 0, templateBuf, bufPos, singleBuf.Length);
           bufPos += singleBuf.Length;
       }
   ```
2. The c++ code does

   ```
   for( int i = 0; i < userHeader.numOfFinger; i++ )
   {
       userHeader.duress[i] = 0; // no duress finger
   }
   ```

   The c# code does:

   ```
       userHdr.duressMask = 0; // no duress finger
   ```

   This is completely different.
3. The c++ code does:

   ```
   for( int i = 0; i < userHeader.numOfFinger * 2; i++ )
   {
       if( i % 2 == 0 )
       {
           userHeader.fingerChecksum[i/2] = 0;
       }
       unsigned char* templateData = templateBuf + i * BS_TEMPLATE_SIZE;
       for( int j = 0; j < BS_TEMPLATE_SIZE; j++ )
       {
           userHeader.fingerChecksum[i/2] += templateData[j];
       }
   }
   ```

   The c# code does:

   ```
       for (int i = 0; i < userHdr.numOfFinger * 2; i++)
       {
           if (i % 2 == 0)
           {
               userHdr.checksum[i / 2] = 0;
           }
           byte[] templateData = templateBuf;
           for (int j = 0; j < 2000 - 1; j++)
           {
               userHdr.checksum[i / 2] += templateData[j];
           }
       }
   ```

   As you can see the c++ code loops twice as many times as the c# code.  The c# code probably should be:

   ```
       for (int i = 0; i < userHdr.numOfFinger; i++)
       {
           if (i % 2 == 0)
           {
               userHdr.checksum[i / 2] = 0;
           }
           for (int j = 0; j < BS_TEMPLATE_SIZE; j++)
           {
               userHdr.checksum[i / 2] += templateBuf[i * BS_TEMPLATE_SIZE + j];
           }
       }
   ```
4. You don't show the c++ call to `BS_EnrollUserBioStation2` in your [pastie](http://pastie.org/9880243) so it can't be compared with the c# call.
5. `userHdr.checksum = new ushort[] { 0 };` looks wrong.  Shouldn't it be something like `userHdr.checksum = new ushort[userHdr.numOfFinger];`

Thus I'd suggest the following:

Update `BSUserHdrEx` as follows:

```
    public const int BS_MAX_NAME_LEN = 32;
    public const int BS_MAX_PASSWORD_LEN = 16;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct BSUserHdrEx
    {
        public static BSUserHdrEx CreateDefaultBSUserHdrEx()
        {
            var userHdr = new BSUserHdrEx();
            userHdr.name = new byte[BSSDK.BS_MAX_NAME_LEN + 1];
            userHdr.department = new byte[BSSDK.BS_MAX_NAME_LEN + 1];
            userHdr.password = new byte[BSSDK.BS_MAX_PASSWORD_LEN];
            userHdr.checksum = new ushort[5];
            return userHdr;
        }

        public uint ID;
        public ushort reserved1;
        public ushort adminLevel;
        public ushort securityLevel;
        public ushort statusMask; // internally used by BioStation
        public uint accessGroupMask;

        //char name[BS_MAX_NAME_LEN + 1];
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = BSSDK.BS_MAX_NAME_LEN + 1)]
        public byte[] name;

        //char department[BS_MAX_NAME_LEN + 1];
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = BSSDK.BS_MAX_NAME_LEN + 1)]
        public byte[] department;

        // char password[BS_MAX_PASSWORD_LEN + 1];
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = BSSDK.BS_MAX_PASSWORD_LEN + 1)]
        public byte[] password;

        public ushort numOfFinger;
        public ushort duressMask;

        //public ushort checksum[5];
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 5)]
        public ushort[] checksum;

        public ushort authMode;
        public ushort authLimitCount; // 0 for no limit
        public ushort reserved;
        public ushort timedAntiPassback; // in minutes. 0 for no limit
        public uint cardID; // 0 for not used
        public bool bypassCard;
        public bool disabled;
        public uint expireDateTime;
        public uint customID; //card Custom ID
        public int version; // card Info Version
        public uint startDateTime;
    };
```

Update `btngetUserInfo_Click` as follows:

```
    private void btngetUserInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int result;

        BSSDK.BSUserHdrEx userHdr = BSSDK.BSUserHdrEx.CreateDefaultBSUserHdrEx();
        userHdr.ID = 2; // 0 cannot be assigned as a user ID
        userHdr.startDateTime = 0; // no check for start date
        userHdr.expireDateTime = 0; // no check for expiry date
        userHdr.adminLevel = BSSDK.BS_USER_NORMAL;
        userHdr.securityLevel = BSSDK.BS_USER_SECURITY_DEFAULT;
        userHdr.authMode = BSSDK.BS_AUTH_MODE_DISABLED; // use the authentication mode of the device
        userHdr.accessGroupMask = 0xffff0201; // a member of Group 1 and Group 2;
        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Madman").CopyTo(userHdr.name, 0);
        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("INC").CopyTo(userHdr.department, 0);
        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("").CopyTo(userHdr.password, 0);
        userHdr.password = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("");  // no password is enrolled. Password should be longer than 4 bytes.
        userHdr.numOfFinger = 2;
        byte[] templateBuf = new byte[userHdr.numOfFinger * 2 * BSSDK.BS_TEMPLATE_SIZE];
        for (int i = 0, bufPos = 0; i < userHdr.numOfFinger * 2; i++)
        {
            byte[] singleBuf = new byte[BSSDK.BS_TEMPLATE_SIZE];
            result = BSSDK.BS_ScanTemplate(m_Handle, singleBuf);
            Array.Copy(singleBuf, 0, templateBuf, bufPos, singleBuf.Length);
            bufPos += singleBuf.Length;
        }
        userHdr.duressMask = 0; // no duress finger

        for (int i = 0; i < userHdr.numOfFinger * 2; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                userHdr.checksum[i / 2] = 0;
            }
            // byte[] templateData = templateBuf;
            for (int j = 0; j < BSSDK.BS_TEMPLATE_SIZE; j++)
            {
                userHdr.checksum[i / 2] += templateBuf[i * BSSDK.BS_TEMPLATE_SIZE + j];
            }
        }

        // enroll the user
        result = BSSDK.BS_EnrollUserBioStation2(m_Handle, ref userHdr, templateBuf);
        if (result == (int)BSSDK.BS_RET_CODE.BS_SUCCESS)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("user " + userHdr.name.ToString() + " enrolled");
        }
```

**update**

The struct you are marshalling is `BSUserHdrEx`.  `BS_EnrollUserBioStation2` does not take this as an argument. `BS_EnrollUserBioStation2` takes a `BS2UserHdr` as an argument (source: Page 158 of "BioStar SDK Manual V1.8.pdf".)  `BSUserHdrEx` is an argument to `BS_EnrollUserEx`. (Page 129).

- `BS_EnrollUserEx` "Enrolls a user to BioStation. Maximum 5 fingers can be enrolled per user."
- `BS_EnrollUserBioStation2` "Enrolls a user to BioStation T2. Maximum 10 fingers per user."

Either you need to switch to the former function, or use the latter data structure.

Comment: thanks alot for the analysis I forgot to add the last line for enroll users but I have updated the pastie now.Let me try make the changes.

Comment: @Gotalove - answer updated.  Without seeing the c++ `BS2UserHdr` class there's not much more I can do.

Comment: @Gotalove - In the c++ there is `faceTemplateBuf` passed to  `BS_EnrollUserBioStation2` which doesn't even exist in c# code.